# aspxcombobox displaying valuefield instead of textfield

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a aspxgridview that handles batch edit mode.
The scenario is when I change the *Product Id* column value, the combobox of the *Version Id* column is repopulated with versions corresponding to the product. Everything is working fine. Product is populated correctly as well as version but on its default value its showing valuefield instead of textfield and when I try to repopulate again the product so that the version will cascade its seems okay. Just with the default value that showing valuefield instead of textfield. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. Please see below for my codes.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var curentEditingIndex;
    var lastCountry = null;
    var isCustomCascadingCallback = false;
    function CountriesCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(s, e) {
        lastCountry = s.GetValue();
        isCustomCascadingCallback = true;
        RefreshData(lastCountry);
    }
    function CitiesCombo_EndCallback(s, e) {
        if (isCustomCascadingCallback) {
            if (s.GetItemCount() > 0)
                sampleGrid2.batchEditApi.SetCellValue(curentEditingIndex, "chndtl_verid", s.GetItem(0).value);
            isCustomCascadingCallback = false;
        }
    }

    function OnBatchEditStartEditing(s, e) {
        curentEditingIndex = e.visibleIndex;
        var currentCountry = sampleGrid2.batchEditApi.GetCellValue(curentEditingIndex, "chndtl_prodid");
        if (currentCountry != lastCountry && e.focusedColumn.fieldName == "chndtl_verid" && currentCountry != null) {
            lastCountry = currentCountry;
            RefreshData(currentCountry);
        }
    }

    function RefreshData(countryValue) {
        hf.Set("CurrentCountry", countryValue);
        version_editor.PerformCallback();
    }

</script>
```

**SqlDataSource**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Product" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DDS %>"         
        SelectCommand="SELECT [p_pcode], [p_pname] FROM [product] WHERE ([p_stat] = @p_stat)  ORDER BY [p_pname]">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="A" Name="p_stat" Type="String" />
                  <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="p_advcde" SessionField="advcde" 
                     Type="String" />
             </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Version" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DDS %>"         
        SelectCommand="SELECT [v_matid], [v_version] FROM [version] WHERE (v_vpcode = @v_vpcode) ORDER BY [v_version]">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="v_vpcode" Type="String" />
                  </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Front-end**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" ClientInstanceName="sampleGrid2" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="fordtl" Theme="Material"  KeyFieldName = "chndtl_id"
        Font-Size="11px" CssClass="ChangeEdit" OnCellEditorInitialize="sampleGrid2_CellEditorInitialize">
    <SettingsEditing Mode="Batch"></SettingsEditing>

    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="chndtl_prodid">
        <PropertiesComboBox EnableCallbackMode="true" CallbackPageSize="30"  DataSourceID="Product" ValueField="p_pcode" TextField="p_pname" ValueType="System.Int32">
        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="CountriesCombo_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </PropertiesComboBox>
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>

    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="chndtl_prod" visible="false"
        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4">
        <SettingsHeaderFilter>
        <DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
        </SettingsHeaderFilter>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="chndtl_version" visible="true"
        ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5" >
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="chndtl_verid" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="6" >
        <PropertiesComboBox EnableCallbackMode="true" OnItemRequestedByValue="OnItemRequestedByValue" 
        OnItemsRequestedByFilterCondition="OnItemsRequestedByFilterCondition"   CallbackPageSize="30" 
        TextField = "v_version" ValueField = "v_matid" ValueType ="System.Int32">
        </PropertiesComboBox>
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>

    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**Backend**

```
 Protected Sub sampleGrid2_CellEditorInitialize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs)
        If e.Column.FieldName = "chndtl_prodid" Then
            e.Editor.ClientInstanceName = "product_editor"
            Dim cmb_prod As ASPxComboBox = CType(e.Editor, ASPxComboBox) 
            cmb_prod.DataSourceID = "Product"
        cmb_prod.ValueField = "p_pcode"
        cmb_prod.TextField = "p_pname"
        cmb_prod.ClientInstanceName = "product_editor"
        cmb_prod.ValueType = GetType(Integer)
        cmb_prod.DataBindItems()
        End If
        If e.Column.FieldName <> "chndtl_verid" Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim editor = CType(e.Editor, ASPxComboBox)
        editor.ClientInstanceName = "version_editor"
        editor.TextField = "v_version"
        editor.ValueField = "v_matid"
        editor.ValueType = GetType(String)
        editor.DataBindItems()
        editor.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "CitiesCombo_EndCallback"

    End Sub
    Protected Sub OnItemsRequestedByFilterCondition(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ListEditItemsRequestedByFilterConditionEventArgs)
        Dim comboBox As ASPxComboBox = DirectCast(source, ASPxComboBox)
        Dim country As Integer = Me.GetCurrentCountry()
        Version.SelectParameters.Clear()
        Version.SelectParameters.Add("filter", TypeCode.String, String.Format("%{0}%", e.Filter))
        Version.SelectParameters.Add("startIndex", TypeCode.Int32, (e.BeginIndex + 1).ToString())
        Version.SelectParameters.Add("endIndex", TypeCode.Int32, (e.EndIndex + 1).ToString())
        If country <> -1 Then
            Version.SelectParameters.Add("v_vpcode", TypeCode.Int32, country.ToString())
            Version.SelectCommand = "SELECT [v_matid], [v_version] FROM (select [v_matid], [v_version], row_number() over (order by t.[v_matid]) as [rn] from [version] as t where ([v_version] LIKE @filter And [v_vpcode] = @v_vpcode)) as st where st.[rn] between @startIndex and @endIndex"
        Else
            Version.SelectCommand = "SELECT [v_matid], [v_version] FROM (select [v_matid], [v_version], row_number() over (order by t.[v_matid]) as [rn] from [version] as t where ([v_version] LIKE @filter)) as st where st.[rn] between @startIndex and @endIndex"

        End If
        comboBox.DataSource = Version
        comboBox.ValueField = "v_matid"
        comboBox.TextField = "v_version"
        comboBox.ValueType = GetType(String)
        comboBox.DataBindItems()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnItemRequestedByValue(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ListEditItemRequestedByValueEventArgs)
        If e.Value Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim comboBox As ASPxComboBox = DirectCast(source, ASPxComboBox)
        Version.SelectParameters.Clear()
        Version.SelectCommand = "SELECT [v_matid], [v_version] FROM [version] WHERE (v_vpcode = @v_vpcode) ORDER BY [v_version]"
        Version.SelectParameters.Add("v_vpcode", TypeCode.String, e.Value.ToString())
        Version.DataBind()
        comboBox.DataSource = Version
        comboBox.ValueType = GetType(String)
        comboBox.ValueField = "v_matid"
        comboBox.TextField = "v_version"
        comboBox.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCurrentCountry() As Integer
        'INSTANT VB NOTE: The variable id was renamed since Visual Basic does not handle local variables named the same as class members well:
        Dim id_Renamed As Object = Nothing
        If hf.TryGet("CurrentCountry", id_Renamed) Then
            Return Convert.ToInt32(id_Renamed)
        End If

        Return -1
    End Function
```

Comment: I think you're forgot to re-bind `chndtl_prodid` combobox using `DataBindItems()` in grid's `CellEditorInitialize` event. Below `e.Editor.ClientInstanceName = "product_editor"` you should make cast as `CType(e.Editor, ASPxComboBox)` & use `DataBindItems()` for binding.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto would you mind to give me a sample? I mean what actually you are trying to suggest?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sorry got confuse. I tried your suggestion but still not working. Put this part  Dim cmb_prod As ASPxComboBox = CType(e.Editor, ASPxComboBox) and bind it again but then no luck. :(

Comment: For what instance that `hf` in `hf.TryGet("CurrentCountry", id_Renamed)` belongs to? I tried to repro your sample in a dummy project & can't find anything about `hf` definition. I still thinking that data re-binding is your current issue with the grid.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the lines referred to get the current country(product) sorry didn't have time to change the variable. This was also a given answer for me in devexpress support. I tried your suggestion but its still not working. The issue that I'm struggling is only occurs on first bind after you select another product the version textfield displaying correctly.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have edited my codes. Please see sampleGrid2_CellEditorInitialize part wherein I put the codes you're suggesting. Thank you.